# How to find the existing collection lists on spring boot mongorepository?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb, mongorepository

First, below is the document class of mongodb,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection="Posts") // The name of collection is "Posts"
public class Post {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String title;

    @Field
    private String body;

    @Field
    private Date createdDate;

    @DBRef 
    private User user;

    @DBRef 
    private Collection<Tag> tags;
}
```

And I made the simple mongorepository interface

```
public interface PostMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

But I have the troubles in loading initial json data into mongodb in service layer,

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "EUC-KR"))) {
            String line;
            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuffer.append(line+ "\n");
            }

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            TypeReference<List<Post>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Post>>(){};
            Collection<Post> posts = objectMapper.readValue(strBuffer.toString(), typeReference);

            // I am stuck on this line
            if(postMongoRepository.FIND_THE_COLLECTION_TITLE) {  

              for(Post post : posts) {
                postMongoRepository.save(post);
              }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

I try to confirm whether the collection "Posts" is generated or not. But I have no idea how to find the existing collections through mongorepository interface. I try to use @Query annotation, but it is limited within key-value, not collection.

I want to find out how to find the existing collection of mongodb database with mongorepository interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all collection names using `MongoOperations.getCollectionNames()`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#getCollectionNames--

There is no way to get this information based on a Spring data Repository.

In normal circumstances there is also no need to check if the collection exists. If it is missing, it will be created by Spring (normally on startup).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have one more question.  Then how can I confirm the existing databases in mongodb. Does MongoRepository have the apis which get the existing mongodb databases lists?

Comment: No. Repositories are for querying one specific collection.